# Is there a constant $c>0$ such that $\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} f\|_\infty\le c\|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}}$ for all $f \in C^{0,\alpha} (\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, bessel-functions, holder-spaces

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \in(0,1)$, let $C^{n, \alpha} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the Hölder space of real-valued functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with continuous derivatives $\{\nabla^i f\}_{0 \leq i \leq n}$ that admit the finite norm
$$
\|f\|_{C^{n, \alpha}} := \sup _{x \neq y} \frac{|\nabla^n f(x)-\nabla^n f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \sum_{i=0}^n \|\nabla^i f\|_{\infty}.
$$

I am investigating the Hölder regularity of the marginal density of a stochastic differential equation. I would like to ask whether the following estimate is true or not, i.e.,

> For $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, there is a constant $c>0$ such that
> $$
> \|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} f\|_{\infty} \leq c\|f\|_{C^{0, \alpha}},
> \quad \forall f \in C^{0, \alpha} (\mathbb{R}^d).
> \tag{$*$} \label{*}
> $$

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: $H^\alpha$ is a very misleading notation for Holder spaces, as it usually denotes the $W^{2,\alpha}$ Sobolev spaces, while Holder spaces are rather denoted $C^{n,\alpha}$

Comment: @LL3.14 I have changed the notation as you suggested.

Comment: It seems a difficult question. It might help you to know that Holder spaces are also the $B^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}$ Besov spaces, and that the spaces with norm $\|(1-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}\|_{L^p}$ are often called Bessel potential spaces (and at leat for $p<\infty$ correspond to Triebel-Lizorkin spaces). In the case where "$\alpha$ is an integer", it seems to depend on the parity of $\alpha$, see Stein Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions (1970), Section 6.6 at p.160.

Comment: Your inequality works if you replace $C^{0,\alpha}$ by $B^\alpha_{\infty,1}$ by the way, and so if you replace $C^{0,\alpha}$ by $C^{0,\beta}$ with $\beta>\alpha$ if it is of any use to you.

Comment: @LL3.14 You meant that: For $0 <\alpha < \beta <1$, there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} f\|_{\infty} \leq c\|f\|_{C^{0, \beta}}$ for all $f \in C^{0, \beta} (\mathbb{R}^d)$, right?

Comment: @LL3.14 In my case, $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. The norm of my interest is $\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} f\|_{\infty}$, not $\|(1-\Delta)^{-\frac{\alpha}{2}} f\|_{\infty}$. Btw, it seems you forgot the minus sign in the definition of Bessel potential spaces.

Comment: No, I think they are usually defined with my (and your) sign convention. At the end, this can of course be defined for $\alpha$ positive or negative. They are just called "potential spaces" in Stein, with $\alpha\geq 0$. Sometimes one can also find the denomination Bessel-Sobolev spaces.

Comment: @LL3.14 It seems from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWxj4.png) screenshot that Stein used the convention with the minus sign.

Comment: No, if $f\in J_\alpha L^p$, then $f = J_\alpha g$ with $g\in L^p$, so $J_{-\alpha}f \in L^p$ ;) You can look at the definition of the norm below too

Comment: @LL3.14 I got it. Could you have a check on my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841995/is-there-a-constant-c0-such-that-1-delta-frac-alpha2-f-infty?noredirect=1#comment10313293_4841995)?

Comment: Yes, your comment is correct

Comment: @LL3.14 I have a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842785/is-there-a-constant-c0-such-that-1-delta-alpha-p-kappa-t-f-c). If you don't mind, please have a look at it. Thank you so much for your consideration!