# Is there a constant $c>0$ such that $\| (1-\Delta)^{-\alpha} P^\kappa_t f\|_{C^{n,\beta}_b}\le c t^{-(\frac{n}{2} - \alpha)^+} \| f \|_{C^{\beta}_b}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, heat-equation, holder-spaces, besov-space

1. For $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, let $C^{n, \alpha}_b (\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of $n$-times continuously differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on $\mathbb R^d$ that admit the finite norm
   $$
   \| f \|_{C^{n , \alpha}_b} :=  \sup_{\substack{x, y \in {\mathbb R}^d \\ 0 <|x-y| \le 1}} \frac{| \nabla^n f (x) - \nabla^n f (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \sum_{k=0}^n \|\nabla^k f\|_{\infty},
   $$
   where $\nabla^k f$ is the $k$-th order Fréchet derivative of $f$. For simplicity, we denote $C^{\alpha}_b (\mathbb R^d) := C^{0 , \alpha}_b (\mathbb R^d)$.
2. For $\kappa >0$, the Gaussian heat kernel $p^\kappa_t$ on $\mathbb R^d$ and its induced operator $P^\kappa_t$ are defined by
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   p^\kappa_t (x) &:= (\kappa \pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{\kappa t}},
   \quad t>0, x \in \mathbb R^d, \\
   P^\kappa_t f (x) &:= \int_{\mathbb R^d}  p^\kappa_t ( x- y) f(y) \, \mathrm d y.
   \end{align*}
   $$

I am investigating the Hölder regularity of the marginal density of a stochastic differential equation. I would like to ask whether the following estimate is true or not, i.e.,

> For $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha, \beta \in (0, 1)$, there is a constant $c >0$ such that
> $$
> \| (1-\Delta)^{- \alpha} P^4_t f\|_{C^{n, \beta}_b} \le c t^{-(\frac{n}{2} - \alpha)^+} \| f \|_{C^{\beta}_b},
> \quad t > 0, f \in C^{\alpha}_b (\mathbb R^d).
> \tag{$*$} \label{*}
> $$

Above, $s^+ := \max \{s, 0\}$ for $s \in \mathbb R$. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: The $\kappa$ is useless, you can always replace $t$ by $\kappa \,t$ instead